# How to prove the inequality for the spectral radius and spectral norm of an arbitrary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-radius, spectral-norm

How to prove $\rho(A)\leq \min_D||D^{-1} A D||_2$, where $D$
is any invertible matrix, $\rho(\cdot)$ is the spectral radius, $\||\cdot\||$ is the spectral norm for the matrix? Are there any other inequalities of this type for the spectral radius and spectral norm for an arbitrary matrix?

Comment: Hint: $\rho(A)=\rho(D^{-1}AD)$.

Comment: I'd suggest using $\text{inf}$ instead of $\min$, otherwise you will need to try proving the existence of a a minimizing $D \in GL_n(\mathbb C)$